# Construction sentence on continuous form

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

It is correct to complete the sentence

> "What......doing with yourself over the last couple of days ?"

with '**are you**' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When you're speaking of "the last couple of days", that is in the recent past. So you'd use the present perfect: "What **have you been** doing with yourself over the last couple of days?"